# Call Form1 component (label) in class

Tags: c#, forms, class, label, call

Good day. I have program with one Form1 and two classes. When i want to use label1 in one of Class it show me error **The name label1 does not exist in the current context.** How i can use label1 in Class for show text?

```
namespace snake_game
{

   public class had
   {

       private Rectangle[] snakeRec;
       private SolidBrush brush;
       private int x, y, width, height;
       public Rectangle[] SnakeRec

       {
           get { return snakeRec; }

       }

       public had()
       {
           snakeRec = new Rectangle[3];
           brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);


           x = 20;
           y = 0;
           width = 10;
           height = 10;
           for (int i = 0; i < snakeRec.Length; i++)
           {
               snakeRec[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
               x -= 10;
           }
}

      ...................................................
```

..............................................................................

```
       public void drawSnake()
       {
           for (int i = snakeRec.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
           {
               snakeRec[i] = snakeRec[i - 1];


               for (int j = 1; j < snakeRec.Length; j++)

                   if (snakeRec[i].X == snakeRec[j].X && snakeRec[i].Y == snakeRec[j].Y)
                   {
                       label1.Text = "------";    //here is problem//
                   }
           }
       }
```

Comment: Too much code. Reduce it to what's needed please.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because you don't want to do that.
You have a class `had`, which is a Model class. You don't want your model to call your View (Label).

You want to build your software with the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern, because it's good. This is the Controller (Form1 code behind), which will call your Model (`had`) for updating the Label of your View (Form1).

For example :

```
public class had
{
    public void moveDown()
    {
       snakeRec[0].Y += 10; 
    }     
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
    private had _model;

    public void moveDown()
    {
       _model.MoveDown();
       this.drawSnake();
    }     
    public void drawSnake()
    {
        for (int i = this._model.snakeRec.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            ....
            label1.Text = "------"; 
            ....
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I want prevent collision with snake body. I tried this          for (int i = snakes.SnakeRec.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                snakes.SnakeRec[i] = snakes.SnakeRec[i - 1];


                for (int j = 1; j < snakes.SnakeRec.Length; j++)

                    if (snakes.SnakeRec[i].X == snakes.SnakeRec[j].X && snakes.SnakeRec[i].Y == snakes.SnakeRec[j].Y)
                    {
                        label1.Text = "--------";
                    }                                                                 But it do not work.